# "End of Statement Expected" Error in VB 2010 in a do while statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a line of code that is working in one statement but not the second statement. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated.  I am learning slowly but surely, and it is by no small margin because of the help I have found here =)   The error is occuring in the `intResult = intSelection x intCount` line of the SECOND `Do` `While` Loop.

The blue squiggle line is under "intCount" just FYI

```
Dim intSelection As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strDisplay As String


Private Sub txtSelection_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSelection.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub btnSelection_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelection.Click
    If intSelection >= 0 And intSelection <= 12 Then
        Do While AdditionToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True And intCount <= 12
            intResult = intSelection + intCount
            strDisplay = intSelection & " + " & intCount & " = " & intResult
            lstResults.Items.Add(strDisplay)
            intCount += 1
        Loop

        Do While MultiplicationToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True And intCount <= 12
            intResult = intSelection x intCount
            strDisplay = intSelection & " x " & intCount & " = " & intResult
            lstResults.Items.Add(strDisplay)
            intCount += 1
        Loop


    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a value between 0 and 12", , "Input Error")


    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intSelection x intCount`  should be intSelection [`*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/583dwz2k.aspx) intCount  Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) it explains the operators that are available for VB.Net

Comment: perfect!  Thank you so much, I should definitely have caught that...  as soon as I'm able I will accept yours as an answer :-)